# How do I trigger a function in an Ember component from the test component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

In the unit test ComponentA-test I would like to trigger the function load() in ComponentA, but I have problems doing so.

Before the assert.equal in the below code example I would like to add something simular to *this.load()* that I would have written in the component to trigger it. But I can't seem to find the right syntax for doing so.

```
    test('should render some information', async function (assert)) {
       await render(hbs`{{componentA}}`);

       assert.euqal(".info").text().trim(), "info text");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple things you can do here but it depends on whether `load` is an action or not. There may be other ways to test this as well, but these are the most common methods I use.

If `load` is an action and is triggered by a DOM event (i.e., clicking a button) then you can trigger the function by performing that DOM event in your integration test:

```
test('should render some information', async function(assert) {
  await render(hbs`{{componentA}}`);

  // if a button has the action modifier:
  // <button {{action "load"}}>Click me</button>
  // then you can do this in your test to trigger the action:

  await click('button');

  // assertions go here
});
```

If it's simply a regular function in the component and you want to call this function manually on an instance of the component you could try doing so in a component unit test. The only gotcha here is that you won't be able to assert any DOM changes.

```
test('should do something', function(assert) {

  const component = this.owner.factoryFor('component:componentA').create();

  component.load();

  // assertions go here
});
```

Comment: It is a regular function, so I will try the second suggestion. Thank you so much!

Comment: @trito you're welcome. just be sure you place this in a unit test file which is not the same as the component's integration test file! It should go in `tests/unit/components/<component_name>-test.js`

Comment: I learned today that Ember doesn't "currently support unit testing of Glimmer components". So it sounds like if you're working with Octane/Glimmer you should not be using component unit tests any longer. See more details in my answer.

Comment: is there any way to programatically invoke a function in ember integration test?

Answer (score 0):

Update for Octane/Glimmer components: I learned today from this [comment](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/18877#issuecomment-614744358) by an Ember core team member that they "don't currently support unit testing of Glimmer components"

Copying a suggested workaround in this [comment](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/18877#issuecomment-675758868) which "let you gain access to the component instance from your rendering tests"

```
module('my-thing', function(hooks) {
  setupRenderingTest(hooks);

  test('something that wants to exercise an internal method', async function(assert) {
    let component;

    this.owner.register('component:my-thing', class extends MyThing {
       constructor(owner, args) {
         super(owner, args);
         component = this;
       }
    });
    
    await render(hbs`<MyThing />`);

    // now I can interact with `component` without issue
  });
});
```